# Python timedelta driving me crazy

Tags: python, timedelta

I have this dataset:

```
        date    event                                 ticker initialprice finalprice
0   2010-11-18  MELA Mela Sciences FDA Panel            MEL     0.0 0.0
1   2010-12-07  OREX Orexigen Therapeutics Inc PDUFA    OREX    0.0 0.0
2   2010-12-07  SLXP SALIX PHARMACEUTICALS LTD PDUFA    SLXP    0.0 0.0
3   2010-12-09  HGSI HUMAN GENOME SCIENCES INC PDUFA    HGSI    0.0 0.0
4   2010-12-16  AZN Astrazeneca PDUFA   AZN 0.0 0.0
```

and I would like to retrieve for each row the stock price for that exact date and for one week before that date, i wrote this code but breaks when i use timedelta:

```
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
for index, row in fda.iterrows():
  try:
    ticker=row['ticker']
    print(ticker)
    end_date0=row['date'].strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    end_date1= row['date'] + timedelta(days=1)
    print(end_date1)
    end_date1=end_date1.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    start_date0=row['date'] - timedelta(days=7)
    start_date1= row['date'] - timedelta(days=6)
    start_date0=start_date0.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    start_date1=start_date1.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    yahoo_financials = YahooFinancials(ticker)
    data = yahoo_financials.get_historical_price_data(start_date=end_date0, 
                                                  end_date=end_date1, 
                                                  time_interval='daily')
    aapl_df = pd.DataFrame(data[ticker]['prices'])
    price=float(aapl_df.iloc[0,4])
    print(end_date0,end_date1,price)
    row['finalprice']=float(price)
    data = yahoo_financials.get_historical_price_data(start_date=start_date0, 
                                                  end_date=start_date1, 
                                                  time_interval='daily')
    aapl_df = pd.DataFrame(data[ticker]['prices'])
    price=float(aapl_df.iloc[0,4])
    print(start_date0,start_date1,price)
    row['initialprice']=float(price)
  except:
    pass
```

Comment: What do you mean by "breaks"? Can you post the error ?

Comment: Get rid of the `try`/`except` until you have it working.  That hides any errors you might have.

Comment: Yes i got rid and it says here :end_date0=row['date'].strftime('%Y-%m-%d') : AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'strftime'

Answer (score 1):

Timedelta can't be add to a string you have to convert the string first to a datetime object:

```
# convert date to datetime obj, using the format in 2nd argument
date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d') 
# add 1 day
added_date = date + timedelta(days=1) 
# convert date back to string if needed
date = date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your date column from string to datetime with `df.date = df.date.astype('datetime64')` and perform the date substraction with `df.date - pd.tseries.offsets.Week()`.

Now, to achieve what you want "retrieve for each row the stock price for that exact date and for one week" you don't need to iterate over the dataframe.

try:

```py
stock_column = 'ticker' # Name of the column that identifies each stock

df.date = df.date.astype('datetime64') # convert date column to datetime type

# Create a multiindex with your date minus 1 week and your stock
multiindex = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(
    (
        (df.date - pd.tseries.offsets.Week()), 
        df[stock_column]
    )
)

# map the columns for initial price and final price for each stock 1 week before
df['initialprice_1_week_before'] = multiindex.map(
    df.set_index(['date', stock_column])['initialprice']
)

df['finalprice_1_week_before'] = multiindex.map(
    df.set_index(['date', stock_column])['finalprice']
)
```